Derived encryption using HKDF and AES keys
I need some orientation regarding the creation of a derivation function that can use and 16 digit number + an AES-128 key to generate a derived AES-128 key.
Would HKDF function be the best for this scenario when developing in JAVA? The derived key generated from HKDF is always the same if the parameters are static? Because I would need to recalculate the derived key more times using the base AES-128 master key plus the 16 digit number to validate access to some data.
I know that AES-128 is not the best security standard, but is the limitation of the host.
So far I didn't try anything because I'm still trying to figure it out the best function o lib that can fit the above scenario.

You can use HmacSHA256 as KDF. Supplying it with the same Key Derivation Key and the same 16 digit number would always yield the same result.
